# autofocus is not working inside promise while working with React-Select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am loading React-Select options asynchronously. Once loading is done, based on the size of options I am updating two states, "placeHolder" and "auto_focus". "placeHolder" is getting updated correctly, But not "auto_focus".

```
var getOptions = _.debounce((input, callback) => {
        axios.get(url_large).then(function (response) {
            response.data.map(function(a){
                a.value = a.id;
                a.label = a.title;
            });              
            callback(null,{options :response.data,complete : true});
            if(response.data.length > 1) {
                this.setState({ auto_focus : true });
                this.setState({ placeHolder : 'Choose From Below  
                                               Options'});
            }               
        }.bind(this));
    },250);
```

am able to see desired output When i log the state of "auto_focus", But not getitng updated over the screen.I tried with updating some other states also. All are working fine except "auto_focus". Could anybody let me know what's the mistake here.

Note : The initial state(either true or false) which is assigned in the constructor is being continued forever, though state is updated later.

Comment: Can I see the intial state?

Comment: @Hana Alaydrus, Initially it is "false" only. At some certain condition I would like to make it "true" .