# What to provide for "store" attribute in <Provider store="" > while working with Redux-store?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Root component need to be wrapped inside like,

```
<Provider store= >
   <App />
</Provider>
```

But, I am not sure about what to provide in store attribute. Could anybody let me know this?

Comment: The redux store - [example](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#indexjs)

Comment: @Ori Drori, What does it mean if we write CreateStore(reducer)? .Here I understood that reducer is nothing but our rootReducer. But basically i didn't understand the complete expression.

Comment: I can't teach you redux using SO comments :) Howerver, I can point you to a (good free course on the subject](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use it to store all reducer like this.

**index.js**

```
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

<Provider store={store}>
   {/*routers here*/}
</Provider>
```

**reducers.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

// reducers import
import MainReducer from './containers/Main/reducer';
import RegisterReducer from './containers/Register/reducer';
import ChangePasswordReducer from './containers/ChangePassword/reducer';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    main: MainReducer,
    register: RegisterReducer,
    changePassword: ChangePasswordReducer
})


export default reducers;
```

Comment: Can i assume that "createStore" is a term that is used to create Store?

Comment: @Kishore Yes you can actually do it this way `const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))`

Comment: This is more meaningful to me than earlier way way of creating ctore. Thanks for clearing the doubt which has been for some time.

Comment: I have posted one question in the same community sometime back. but i didn't  get any suggestion. Could you have a look at it--[autofocus is not working inside promise while working with React-Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540146/autofocus-is-not-working-inside-promise-while-working-with-react-select)

Comment: @Kishore I'll try my best to help